# I want my div's to be next to each other, but when the screen gets smaller, they should go under each other

Tags: html, css

My Website is split into 3 divs which are horizontal next to each other and I want them to go under each other as the screen gets smaller. They do it, but then the margin on the left side is smaller than the margin on the right side. I don't know what to change

```css
.card-block {
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-right: 15%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.card-block .card-block-content {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 auto;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
  width: 33.2%;
  min-width: 300px;
}

.card-block .card-block-content p {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-block">
  <div class="card-block-content" style="background-color: red;">
    <p> 1 </p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-block-content" style="background-color: green;">
    <p> 2 </p>
  </div>
  <div class="card-block-content" style="background-color: blue;">
    <p> 3 </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's because of the `float`, take a look into _Flexbox_ or _the Grid_ in combination with the _media queries_ for an easy solution.

Comment: what is the status of the question? You have been given a few answers, but none were accepted in order to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify how your website will look in determined specs by using CSS media queries https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 0):

you should use a media-screen query and in specific width you should put your float to none and margin to auto. then it should work.

```
@media screen and (max-width:900px) {
.card-block .card-block-content{float:none; margin: auto}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS flexbox is a good way to handle this kind of behavior.

See the code snippet below.

```css
.card-block {
width: 70%;
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
margin-left: 15%;
margin-right: 15%;
background-color: lightgrey;
margin: auto;
}

.card-block .card-block-content {
padding: 0px;
border-right: 1px solid black;
width: 33.2%;
min-width: 300px;
display: flex;
flex: 1;
}

.card-block .card-block-content p {
padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-block">
<div class="card-block-content" style="background-color: red;">
  <p> 1 </p>
</div>
<div class="card-block-content" style="background-color: green;">
  <p> 2 </p>
</div>
<div class="card-block-content" style="background-color: blue;">
  <p> 3 </p>
</div>
```

Hope this helps :)